# Why do stars appear on my save file icon for New Super Mario Bros. Wii?

Tags: new-super-mario-bros-wii

I just finished beating Bowser in New Super Mario Bros. Wii and now there are some stars on my save file icon.  What do they mean and how do I earn them?  How many are there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 5 stars in total. They basically tell you how "complete" your file is.

- To get Star 1, you have to beat the game.
- To get Star 2, you have to beat every normal level.
- To get Star 3, you have to get all (207) Star Coins from the first 8 worlds.
- To get Star 4, you have to get all (24) Star Coins in World 9.
- To get Star 5, you have find every secret goal and use every warp cannon.

You can also get "sparkling stars" by beating the game without the Super Guide appearing.

Comment: Is there a sixth star? When you play the game, it keeps track of how many points you have... I was just thinking, what if you get the point counter to all 99999999's? does that give you another star? I have already made it to approx 360,0000000....

Comment: I haven't seen a single reference for getting sparkling stars without *using* the Super Guide (in fact, a few people are quite angry that they have accidentally made the Super guide *appear*), so I have reverted my answer.